# CLion won't print in console after scanf

Tags: c

Console in CLion won't print line after scaning input, but in iTerm after compiling it all works perfectly. 
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char personName;
    printf("Hello, what is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", personName);
    printf("Hello, %s\n", personName);
    return 0;
}
```

I just got this in CLion console:

```
Hello, what is your name?
Mike

Process finished with exit code 11
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour  `personName` is not a string.

Comment: You need to allocate space for the string.  `personName` is a single char, but you are trying to read a multi-character string into it.  That leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: How it works in iTerm? @NeilButterworth

Comment: Half of the tags were completely irrelevant. Pick one C or C++, but know that if this is intended to be C++, you're being educated from sources about 25 years out of date.

Comment: Undefined behaviour has undefined results. I doesn't work in iTerm. It merely LOOKS like it works.

Comment: Compilers [warn about this](https://godbolt.org/g/AcPtSa).

Comment: Worthwhile reading so that next time you see Process finished with exit code 11 you know what it means: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103254/meaning-of-exit-code-11-in-c

Comment: I just add [50] at the end of char personName and that's a solution. Thank you everyone. :)

Comment: That works until someone puts in a 51 character long name.

Comment: It's ok for now, If you know how to help, please, not just looking for mistakes in question.  @user4581301

Comment: No offence intended. It is OK for now. This is a common problem in C and not trivial to solve because you cannot easily change the size of an array based on the input. In C++, you use `std::string` and iostreams. `std::string name; std::cin >> name;` will work so long as you don't have a compound name like "Billy Bob".

Comment: @user4581301 Off by 1.  With `add [50]`, that works until someone puts in a 50 character long name.

Comment: Yep. Forgot the terminator. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an array for `personName`. The code will be,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char personName[32];
    printf("Hello, what is your name?\n");
    if(scanf("%s", personName))
        printf("Hello, %s\n", personName);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a length as short as 10, while an order of magnitude better than the question, is not 'safe'; it is far too easy to overflow.  It would be best to use `char personName[32];` and `if (scanf("%31s", personName) == 1) printf("Hello, %s\n", personName);`.  The different-by-one on the lengths is unfortunate but hallowed by history and enshrined in the standards.